# Yupe cложная авторизация по номеру подразделения и роли?

Tags: yii

Вот буквально сегодня установил yupe, но вижу, что в стандартном комплекте разделение какое-то хилое. Админ\пользователь. Как же так? Ведь yii очень гибкая система, и он не только для блогов и интернет-магазинов.

Подскажите - закусывать ножку от табуретки и разгребать стандартный yii, ломать yupe или есть готовые решения?
Млин такая система, а достойной реализации в стандартном функционале нет?

В общем, мысль следующая - пользователей я вручную ввожу в базу mysql, у них должны быть следующие поля id, login, pass, role, id_page. Ненавижу это поле email!!!! Как его отключить?
В общем, на основании роли и ид разрешенной страницы ему пхп скрипт должен отдавать различные страницы (ид страницы) с различным функционалом (роль), пост или гет там.
Что самое смешное, что такой функционал на чистом пхп пишется за пару вечеров под пиво, а в крутой цмс его нет?

Кто реально сталкивался\решает эту проблему?

UPD

нужна аутентификация на основании данных базы пользователей. при этом если роль - мастер, то он может добавлять строки в базу (предположим какие то приборы), в свой цех. а роль электрик - он может смотреть данные своего участка (цех состоит из участков), и править некоторые параметры данных, введенных мастером по его участку(причем только некоторые, удалять записи и изменять серийник он не может, может изменить количество предположим, состояние). и получаем иерахическую структуру - админ может все, руководство может смотреть все цеха. мастер смотрит и правит свой цех (тоже с ограничениями, удалить запись у него возможности нет). а электрик смотрит свой участок и может редактировать поле состояние (сломан, в ремонте, работает)

Comment: Возьми пива и прочитай мануал по Юпи Цмс.

Comment: Вы правильно говорите, что Yii-гибкая система, но это фреймворк, а не готовый продукт. Yupe- CMS (почти готовый продукт), написанная на Yii. На оф.сайте Yupe написано: 

Юпи! позволяет быстро и легко создавать следующие <b>типовые</b> проекты: сайты-визитки,корпоративные порталы,коллективные и персональные блоги,каталоги товаров,интернет-магазины. (http://yupe.ru/pages/about)

Поэтому не стоит путать фреймворк и CMS, это все-таки разные вещи для разных целей. Требуемый вами функционал отличается от типового, поэтому CMS подходит не полностью. Пожалуйста подробнее опишите что вы хотите получит

Comment: тоже интересует роли,права доступа к контенту, было бы интересно взглянуть как вы решили задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь проблема не только в авторизации, все гораздо глубже.

Yupe - CMS для быстрого создания типовых сайтов (сайты-визитки, интернет-магазины ...). Поставили, выбрали модули, натянули дизайн - готово!

Вы же хотите получить информационно-экономическую систему управления бизнес-процессами предприятия. Скорее всего вы не найдете подходящий готовый продукт (на Yupe 100% нет) и придется проектировать собственную, с учетом всех особенностей именно вашего предприятия.

PS: и да, за пару вечеров под пиво на PHP оно не сделается

Comment: в общем то да. задача оказалась типовая но в готовом виде не встречается. сча сижу разбираюсь с yii с ролями и rbac

Answer (score 1):

Из описания видно, что это не сайт, а некая ЦРМ система. Вопрос, зачем её писать на движке для сайта? Возьмите и напишите свою, раз не можете разобраться в чужой.